# Replace background image given an array of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to set a background image rotation for a div with a image already in it, doesn't seem to change anything, thought I would check if someone could see the problem since no errors come up.

```
 <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
        var tips = [
        "header.jpg",
        "header2.jpg",
        "header3.jpg",
        "header4.jpg",
        "header5.jpg",

        ];
        var i = 0;
         if (i == tips.length) --i;
    $('.containercoloring').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function()
    {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + tips[i] + ')');
    }).delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    i++;
    }, 5 * 1000);
    });
    </script>
    <body>
    <div class="containercoloring"> </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Try to put counter (var i =0) outside setInterval()... Hint: https://jsfiddle.net/qk2L8L2d/ Your i will always be 1, whenever you run function, since you declared it inside function... (just first incrementation works).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working(updated) code.  I hope you are importing jquery lib separately.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            var tips = [
                "header.jpg",
                "header2.jpg",
                "header3.jpg",
                "header4.jpg",
                "header5.jpg"
            ];
            var imageIndex = ++i % tips.length;
            $('.containercoloring').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function() {
                $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + tips[imageIndex] + ')');
            }).delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
        }, 5 * 1000);
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div class="containercoloring" style="height: 100px;">Image Container</div>
</body>
```

You can test here in this jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nbq9f6bg/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So there were a couple of notes I had about your example. Please see the comments below. I used background color and removed the transitions to show it easier.

```js
// declare variables
var tips = [
  "#ff9000",
  "#ff0000",
  "#0099ff"
];

// counter
var i = 0;

// direction
var direction = 'forwards';

// time in between intervals
var timer = 2000;

function changeBackground() {
  // Check the length minus 1 since your counter starts at 0
  if (i == (tips.length - 1)) {
    direction = 'backwards';
  } else if(i == 0) {
    // only set the direction back to forwards when the counter is 0 again
    direction = 'forwards';
  }
  $('.containercoloring').css('background-color', tips[i]); 
    
  // add or subtract based on the direction 
  if(direction == 'forwards') {
    i++;
  } else {
    i--;
  }
}


$( document ).ready(function() {
  // save interval to a variable so you can stop it later
  var theInterval = setInterval(changeBackground, timer);
  
  // run the function since the interval will take 2000ms to execute
  changeBackground();
});
```

```css
.containercoloring {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containercoloring"> </div>
```